# Advise needed - which Rapid Application Development Framework using PHP and MVC meets this specific need?

Tags: model-view-controller, crud, scaffolding, php, rbac

we are a parents initiative who runs a small kindergarden / child nursery and we set out to build a basic web based documentation and reporting application for our nursery.

After spending a week doing research on the various PHP MVC frameworks, I have a few questions that I could not answer myself - even after having a closer look (installed on local machine) at CakePHP, Symfony, CodeIgniter, YII and Joomla.

The goal is to build a web application where site managers, staff and parents (roles) can log in to do simple tasks, depending on their role (hence I need a RBAC). Site managers will for example be able to add staff to the database, staff will be able to add children and do some documenation on children (select a child and enter details on special needs etc.). Parents should be able to update information about who is picking up the child, or inform the staff if a child will not come in at a certain date.

Now, since this is all basic CRUD with only a few tables underneath, tables connected via some foreign key constraints, I would like the framework to generate CRUD skeletons for me.

And since I need to manage roles and limit access to certain pages, I would like a basic user management out of the box.

Plus, PHP and MySQL and MVC are set - otherwise I would have used Oracle Apex as I have some experience with that.

So, I looked at a vast amount of PHP frameworks and found the following to be promising:

- CodeIgniter (with Bonfire plugin)
- Symfony2
- YII framework with GII
- CakePHP
- Joomla

BUT none of the frameworks I looked at seemed to fit my need:

1. creating CRUD skeleton pages based on my ERD with foreign keys (MySQL InnoDB) / Scaffolding
2. offering a basic user management out of the box with up to date security measures in place (passwords stored using phpass or salted hashes & md5, user registration, defining roles and limiting tasks to roles/users).

If somebody could suggest a PHP Framework that comes with those two requirements build in, I would be very happy to hear about it. THANK YOU very much in advance!!

(I really liked CodeIgniter because it was simple to set up and lightweight, I liked the Bonfire user management plugin but was disappointed when I found out they sacked scaffolding in the lasted release
And I liked Joomla for its user management, but found it quite hard to get started on component development, plus no scaffolding).

Answer (score 0):

You should check FuelPHP and its ORM, Oil and Auth packages. It's really great. If you liked CodeIgniter, you'll probably love Fuel.

http://www.fuelphp.com

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo, I will go and check that out. And although I had tagged my post with PHP and had ruled out Ruby on Rails beforehand, I now definitely will give that a try as well...

Comment: If you're open to other languages, Django fits perfectly your needs (http://www.djangoproject.com). You may define the models (children, parents etc) and the Admin interface would build the CRUD automagically (although you retain control over everything). You'll have built-in security included (CRSF protection, DB/output escaping etc) and the Auth system provides the roles/functionality you mentioned out of the box. Much better than Rails, IMHO.